# Spin counter to a number containing two digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used the jQuery animate function to help with a spin to number counter. The following [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mHtBv) demos this.

Here is the function:

```
function statsSpin(IDofObject, stat, duration) {
  $({countNum: $(IDofObject).text()}).animate({countNum: stat}, {
    duration: duration,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $(IDofObject).text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $(IDofObject).text(this.countNum);
    }

  });
};
```

As it stands it spins from a single decimal place e.g. 0 to 14 on day, month and year. How can I modify so that is spins from 00-00-00 to 08-09-14?

Comment: Check updated codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vfoDj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is pad your numbers with a `0`  if the value is less than 10.  Since you need to do this twice I just created a simple utiltity function for it

```
function statsSpin(IDofObject, stat, duration) {
  $({countNum: $(IDofObject).text()}).animate({countNum: stat}, {
    duration: duration,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      var num = padNumber(Math.floor(this.countNum));          
      $(IDofObject).text(num);
    },
    complete: function() {
      $(IDofObject).text(padNumber(this.countNum));
    }

  });
};

function padNumber( num){
  return num < 10 ? '0'+num : num;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GIvwA)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the **[slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** function to add leading 0's to digits. If you change your `step` and `complete` functions to the following it should work:

```
function statsSpin(IDofObject, stat, duration) {
    $({
        countNum: $(IDofObject).text()
    }).animate({
        countNum: stat
    }, {
        duration: duration,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function () {
            var num = ("0" + Math.floor(this.countNum)).slice(-2);
            $(IDofObject).text(num);
        },
        complete: function () {
            var num = ("0" + this.countNum).slice(-2);
            $(IDofObject).text(num);
        }
    });
};
```

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/32mwu49e/)** for an example. We add a leading 0 to the number and take the last two characters of the resulting string.